# How to find specific data in XML POST Response?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm tasked with retrieving specific data from an XML POST Response.

Here's an example of the XML Reply:

```
<ServiceHistoryArray>
    <RecordID>XD116067*401529</RecordID>
    <SWR>
        <V Idx="1">7932</V><V Idx="2">7932</V><V Idx="3">7932</V><V Idx="4">7932</V>
    </SWR>
    <Comments/>
    <Mileage>6</Mileage>
    <Operation>
        <V Idx="1">Z7000*WPDIP****PRE-DELIVERY INSPECTION - BASE TIME</V><V Idx="2">Z911*INC****ETCH WINDOWS</V><V Idx="3">B0048*WPBS4****FASCIA, FRONT BUMPER - REPLACE ONE PIECE</V><V Idx="4">9997*WPBS4****</V>
    </Operation>
    <CloseDate>1998-12-30</CloseDate>
    <OpenDate>1998-10-16</OpenDate>
    <PartsAmount>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V><V Idx="2">0.00</V><V Idx="3">166.32</V><V Idx="4">0.00</V>
    </PartsAmount>
    <LaborAmount>
        <V Idx="1">64.80</V><V Idx="2">3.60</V><V Idx="3">140.40</V>
    </LaborAmount>
    <Warranty>
        <S Idx="1">&#xfc;96&#xfc;0&#xfd;&#xfd;10232632&#xfc;4H&#xfc;1</S><S Idx="2">&#xfc;96&#xfc;0&#xfd;&#xfd;10232632&#xfc;4H&#xfc;1</S><S Idx="3">&#xfc;96&#xfc;0&#xfd;&#xfd;10232632&#xfc;4H&#xfc;1</S>
    </Warranty>
</ServiceHistoryArray>
```

I need to concatenate all of the related "V" elements' inner text.

Ex:
7392 Z700*WDIP****PRE-DELIVERY INSPECTION - BASE TIME 0.00 64.80
7392 Z911*INC****ETCH WINDOWS 0.00 3.60
etc...

Here's my code thus far:

```
// String variable to store the XML POST Reply
   string replyString = WebRequestPostData("http://" + maskedTextBox1.Text + ":" + maskedTextBox2.Text, payload);


    XmlDocument replyDoc = new XmlDocument();  // New XmlDocument from reply
    replyDoc.LoadXml(replyString);
    XmlNodeList list = replyDoc.SelectNodes("//ServiceHistoryArray/*");  // XmlNodeList based on child elements of <ServiceHistoryArray> node.

    var nodees = new List<XmlNode>(list.Cast<XmlNode>().ToArray());

    // Finds Mileage, CloseDate, and OpenDate values and displays them on form.
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodees)
    {
        switch (node.Name)
        {
            case "OpenDate":
                textBox1.Text = node.InnerText;
                break;
            case "CloseDate":
                textBox2.Text = node.InnerText;
                break;
            case "Mileage":
                textBox3.Text = node.InnerText;
                break;
        }
    }

    // This section is supposed to display the concatenated values of the <V> elements:
    for (int i = 0; i < nodees.Count; i++)
    {
        if (nodees[i].HasChildNodes)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nodees[i].ChildNodes.Count; j++)
            {
                switch (nodees[i].ChildNodes[j].NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Text:
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        switch (nodees[i].ChildNodes[j].Attributes[0].Value)
                        {

                            case "1":
                                Console.WriteLine("1-" + nodees[i].ChildNodes[j].InnerText + " ");
                                break;
                            case "2":
                                Console.WriteLine("2-" + nodees[i].ChildNodes[j].InnerText + " ");
                                break;
                            case "3":
                                Console.WriteLine("3-" + nodees[i].ChildNodes[j].InnerText + " ");
                                break;
                            case "4":
                                Console.WriteLine("4-" + nodees[i].ChildNodes[j].InnerText + " ");
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The concatenated values will need to be displayed in a listBox control. Additionally, I need to try and code this process NOT to anticipate a set number of  elements; in this case there are 4. Some other instances of the POST Request may return 10 or 2 or whatever.

I realize that this may or may not impact other users but hopefully I'm not the only one out there with this problem...

Comment: First change: use LINQ to XML if you possibly can. It's a much simpler XML API.

Comment: I know... I see that response in regard to Xml on here all the time.  I really need to learn that.  However, any input using the "old" method would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(replyString);
var query = from v in xdoc.Descendants("V")
            group v by (int)v.Attribute("Idx") into g
            select String.Join(" ", g.Select(x => (string)x));
```

This query selects all `V` elements in document and groups them by `Idx` atribute value (in order elements appear in document). Then all values of elements in group are concatenated into string. Query will contain:

```
"7932 Z7000*WPDIP****PRE-DELIVERY INSPECTION - BASE TIME 0.00 64.80"
"7932 Z911*INC****ETCH WINDOWS 0.00 3.60"
"7932 B0048*WPBS4****FASCIA, FRONT BUMPER - REPLACE ONE PIECE 166.32 140.40"
"7932 9997*WPBS4**** 0.00"
```

Comment: So, I've never used Linq to XML I'm a total noob in this area.  Can you clarify how to view the contents of query?  *** I am researching this topic as I type this comment...

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!  You have essentially "forced" me into Linq to XML and I'm diggin' it!  I was able to get the contents of query into the listbox without problems. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Lazy - So, to add to this... how would you recommend adding the <S> elements into the query.  I'd like to concatenate the <S> element values into the appropriate <V> element strings. For example, <S Idx = "1">, I'd like to add this to the end of each related "line".  I hope that makes sense...

Comment: @PDXWReX sorry, was AFK. To select both `V` and `S` elements you can use `XPathSelectElements("//V|//S")` instead of `Descendants("V")`. For quick start with LINQ to XML you can use [this overview](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - Thanks for clarification and the link to getting started with Linq to XML!  You've been a great help!